# Can i create message box which will be seen/popup on current screen/home screen in Android?

Tags: android

i want to create message box which must be seen on current screen(Ex i am playing song or creating message on that screen also that message must got pop-up/seen)like notification..
so.please help me to achieve this.....

Thanks in Advance--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) to accomplish what you wish, it will be visible over the activity/screen and can be styled with a custom layout.

You may also want to read the [Android Developer documentation on Notifying the User](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html) for other alternatives & common methods of notification on Android.

Comment: hi your right but i want to put the buttons on it?and i guess there is no chance to put buttons on Toast...so there any idea to put image on whole screen or lock that screen..?

Comment: @Danny: Just FYI, any app that popped up a full screen image/dialog in front of another running app on my phone would be uninstalled immediately.

Comment: @Danny I'm not saying whether can or cannot achieve what you're trying to do. I'm just saying that as a user I'd be extremely annoyed by any app that did this. One of Android's strengths is its unobtrusive notification system. Good apps work with it, not around it.

Comment: @laurence yes ur rght..but actually i want notification as message box..on screen....how we can achieve it??

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a normal android notification would be better.  IF you do want to do this though, take a look at the "Creating a Custom Dialog" section here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: yes right but whether that dialog box will be seen on home screen or on any current running application..??